# Facebook SDK android, get connected accounts

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A facebook user can control multiple pages. For example, a user can have their personal facebook account, their public figure page and their business page. This shows up as three distinct accounts with their own `User` information in facebook's server.

I want to list these things, how can I retrieve what these accounts are using the Facebook SDK?

I feel like it has to do with the `Request.newMeRequest` method, but this returns a `GraphUser` object.

and the `Request.newMyFriendsRequest` returns a list of users, but not a list of the personal account's connected accounts.

**edit** I am now using this

```
 new com.facebook.Request(
                            session,
                            "/me/accounts",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new com.facebook.Request.Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) {
                                    if(response!=null && response.getGraphObjectList()!=null){

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    ).executeAsync();
```

but `response` is null. My session has the `manage_pages` permission requested as well

**edit** I tried replacing `"/me/accounts"` with `"/"+userId+"/accounts"` and I still get back a null response. Baffling.

Insight appreciated

Comment: do you have the active session ?

Comment: try with graph explorer, if you are getting response ?

Comment: "me/accounts" works for me with manage_pages permission. Is your app public? And if not, does the user making these requests have the right roles in your app (admin/developer/tester)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this procedure at [Graph Api Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/accounts) -> Just click on 'Get Access Token' button-> under 'Extended permission' check 'manage_pages' & submit it. It will give you the admin-page-details JSON.
And please see [Graph API Reference /{user-id}/accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/accounts)